# Split binary string into 31bit strings

Tags: python, split, binary

I have a binary string and I want to split it into 31 bits array

1101000011010010010000001101101011110010010000001101110011000010110110101100101001000000110100101110011001000000110000101101110011001110110000101110100

That is just an example of a binary string but I need it to work for any binary string keeping the integrity of the binary string if I want to rejoin the array. Once the array is made append 0's to the front making sure the length of everything is 31.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with *binary string*? A string containing only 0s and 1s?

Comment: What happens if the array is not a multiple of 31?

Comment: Also I need to be able to append 0's to make sure the size is 31 of each block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **regex**!

Here

> {n,m} Matches at least n and at most m occurrences of the preceding expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '1101000011010010010000001101101011110010010000001101110011000010110110101100101001000000110100101110011001000000110000101101110011001110110000101110100'
>>> re.findall(r'.{,30}''.',s)
['1101000011010010010000001101101', '0111100100100000011011100110000', '1011011010110010100100000011010', '0101110011001000000110000101101', '110011001110110000101110100']
```

To pad the item which isn't of len 31 with 0's you can use [**str.ljust**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust)

```
>>> [i.ljust(31,'0') for i in re.findall(r'.{,30}''.',s)]
['1101000011010010010000001101101', '0111100100100000011011100110000', '1011011010110010100100000011010', '0101110011001000000110000101101', '1100110011101100001011101000000']
```

**Time for execution:**

```
0.000314
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why would you use a regex if the content clearly does not matter? Furthermore what if the string is **not** a multiple of 31?

Comment: Thanks! That was a good catch indeed @WillemVanOnsem. I've added the edits.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to append 0's so all of the strings have equal length?>

Comment: I've added the edits! You can use str.ljust over your regex result!